# resultset::getString() method make wrong

Tags: mysql-connector

I built a database and a table as follows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZaj6.png)

I want to fetch the data of Column 1 which type is String,so I use some c++ codes as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include "mysql_driver.h"
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "cppconn/driver.h"
#include "cppconn/statement.h"
#include "cppconn/prepared_statement.h"
#include "cppconn/metadata.h"
#include "cppconn/exception.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace sql;

int main()
{
    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver = 0;
    sql::Connection *conn = 0;

    try
    {
        driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
        conn = driver->connect("tcp://localhost:3306/jwsystem", "root", "123456");
        cout << "success" << endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "fail" << endl;
    }
    sql::Statement* stat = conn->createStatement();
    stat->execute("set names 'gb2312'");
    ResultSet *res;
    res = stat->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sss");
    while (res->next())
    {
        cout << "ss\t" << res->getInt("ss") << endl;
        cout << "s\t" << res->getString("s") << endl;
    }

    if (conn != 0)
    {
        delete conn;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

I can fetch Column 1 which type is Int, but I can't get Column 2 which type is String.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYu0w.png)

only prompt program ending.

I think that if I can fetch Column 2 I can fetch Column 1 .

So the getString（） method must be something wrong.Can you solve this problem? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you have to call c_str() function on the returned values from getString, I'm not sure what the reason is and there doesn't appear to be anything that shows this, but doing this method fixes the issue.

For example.

```
res->getString("s").c_str();
```